# Python: create a function to modify a list by reference not value

Tags: python, list

I'm doing some performance-critical Python work and want to create a function that removes a few elements from a list if they meet certain criteria.  I'd rather not create any copies of the list because it's filled with a lot of really large objects.

Functionality I want to implement:

```
def listCleanup(listOfElements):
    i = 0
    for element in listOfElements:
        if(element.meetsCriteria()):
            del(listOfElements[i])
        i += 1
    return listOfElements

myList = range(10000)
myList = listCleanup(listOfElements)
```

I'm not familiar with the low-level workings of Python.  Is myList being passed by value or by reference?

How can I make this faster?

Is it possible to somehow extend the list class and implement listCleanup() within that?

```
myList = range(10000)
myList.listCleanup()
```

Thanks-

Jonathan

Comment: I think you will find that this line of thinking is more trouble than it's worth.  Just copy the list, modify it, and return the modified copy.  Modifying a list in place while iterating it is just asking for headaches.

Comment: `del` is a statement, not a function.  Don't wrap its argument in parentheses.

Comment: The size of the object "in the list" is irrelevant as Python isn't storing the object in the list; it's storing a reference to the object.  Thus performance issues are related to the length of the list and the algorithm used to operate on the list rather than the size of the objects referred to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Python passes everything the same way, but calling it "by value" or "by reference" will not clear everything up, since Python's semantics are different than the languages for which those terms usually apply. If I was to describe it, I would say that all passing was by value, and that the value was an object reference. (This is why I didn't want to say it!)

If you want to filter out some stuff from a list, you build a new list

```
foo = range(100000)
new_foo = []
for item in foo:
    if item % 3 != 0: # Things divisble by 3 don't get through
        new_foo.append(item)
```

or, using the list comprehension syntax

```
 new_foo = [item for item in foo if item % 3 != 0]
```

Python will not copy the objects in the list, but rather both `foo` and `new_foo` will reference the same objects. (Python never implicitly copies any objects.)

---

You have suggested you have performance concerns about this operation. Using repeated  `del` statements from the old list will result in not code that is less idiomatic and more confusing to deal with, but it will introduce quadratic performance because the whole list must be reshuffled each time.

To address performance:

- **Get it up and running.** You can't figure out what your performance is like unless you have code working. This will also tell you whether it is speed or space that you must optimize for; you mention concerns about both in your code, but oftentimes optimization  involves getting one at the cost of the other.
- **Profile.** You can use [the stdlib tools](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) for performance in time. There are various third-party memory profilers that can be somewhat useful but aren't quite as nice to work with.
- **Measure.** [Time](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) or reprofile memory when you make a change to see if a change makes an improvement and if so what that improvement is.
- To make your code more memory-sensitive, you will often want a paradigm shift in how you store your data, not microoptimizastions like not building a second list to do filtering. (The same is true for time, really: changing to a better algorithm will almost always give the best speedup. However, it's harder to generalize about speed optimizations).

  Some common paradigm shifts to optimize memory consumption in Python include

  1. Using Generators. Generators are lazy iterables: they don't load a whole list into memory at once, they figure out what their next items are on the fly. To use generators, the snippets above would look like

     ```
     foo = xrange(100000) # Like generators, xrange is lazy
     def filter_divisible_by_three(iterable):
         for item in foo:
             if item % 3 != 0:
                 yield item

     new_foo = filter_divisible_by_three(foo)
     ```

     or, using the generator expression syntax,

     ```
     new_foo = (item for item in foo if item % 3 != 0)
     ```
  2. Using `numpy` for homogenous sequences, especially ones that are numerical-mathy. This can also speed up code that does lots of vector operations.
  3. Storing data to disk, such as in a database.

Comment: pb[r]v (pass-by-[reference]-value) can actually be applied to many, many languages including (but not limited to) Ruby, Java and C#. (Each with slightly different subtleties/mechanics based on 'type' passed). However, I much prefer to say "an object is itself" and "an object is not copied/cloned/duplicated implicitly when invoking a function" (for immutable/val types, even if this is a lie, the semantics work out similar) when discussing pb[r]v semantics. It is very consistent across most imperative languages allows one to "look past" references/pointers when dealing with High Level languages.

Comment: it could be a good ideo to use python `timeit` for profiling.

Comment: The terms can certainly be applied to a very wide range of languages. In my experience, when someone hears that Python is one or the other, they think this entails things that are not not true being true. Categorizing Python as "pass by value" usually makes people think they can take mental shortcuts relying on additional information about Python's semantics which are not true.

Comment: @kriss, timeit isn't really suitable for *profiling*, but it is suitable for timing to do microoptimizations for the bottnecks you found profiling. I link to the timeit documentation in my post, though it's hard to see since links don't really stand out all that much on SO.

Comment: """the whole list must be reshuffled each time""" (1) "shuffle" is ambiguous (it's not being shuffled like a deck of cards) (2) whatever you call it, after del alist[i], the operation is moving the alist[i+1:] pointers down by one slot; it doesn't involve the *whole* list.

Comment: Yes, that was ambiguous. By "shuffle" I was trying to form a word picture of all the little pointers shuffling their little feet to scootch down the array. By "whole list" I was incorrectly referring to the O(n)ness of delitem for lists.

Answer (score 6):

In Python, lists are always passed by reference.

The size of the objects in the list doesn't affect the lists performance, because the lists only stores references to the objects.  However, the number of items in the list does affect the performance of some operations - such as removing an element, which is O(n).

As written, listCleanup is worst-case O(n**2), since you have the O(n) del operation within a loop that is potentially O(n) itself.

If the order of the elements doesn't matter, you may be able to use the built-in `set` type instead of a list.  The `set` has O(1) deletions and insertions.  However, you will have to ensure that your objects are immutable and hashable.

Otherwise, you're better off recreating the list.  That's O(n), and your algorithm needs to be at least O(n) since you need to examine every element.  You can filter the list in one line like this:

```
listOfElements[:] = [el for el in listOfElements if el.MeetsCriteria()]
```

Comment: Switiching from a `list` to a `set` probably isn't a great way to attempt to save memory. `;)`

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't really do anything memory-saving or otherwise beneficial over the more standard Python techniques like `listOfElements = [el for el in listOfElements if el.MeetsCriteria()]` as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't really see any reason we know of such that slice assignment is called for here. Occasionally it is essential to mutate the original list, but it isn't the typical situation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like premature optimization. You should try to get a better understanding of how python works before trying to optimize.

In this particular case you don't need to worry about object size. Copying a list is using list comprehension or slice will only perform surface copy (copy references to objects even if the term does not really apply well to python). But the number of items in the list may matter because del is O(n). There may be other solutions, like replacing an item with None or a conventional Null object, or using another data structure like a set or a dictionary where cost of deleting item is much lower.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone mentioned actually using filter. Since a lot of the answers came from well respected people, I'm sure that I'm the one that's missing something. Could someone explain what would be wrong with this:

`new_list = filter(lambda o: o.meetsCriteria(), myList)`

Answer (score 1):

modifying your data structure as you're iterating over it is like shooting yourself in the foot... iteration fails. you might as well take others' advice and just make a new list:

```
myList = [element for element in listOfElements if not element.meetsCriteria()]
```

the old list -- if there are no other references to it -- will be deallocated and the memory reclaimed. better yet, don't even make a copy of the list. change the above to a *generator expression* for a more memory-friendly version:

```
myList = (element for element in listOfElements if not element.meetsCriteria())
```

all Python object access is by reference. objects are created and variables are just references to those objects. however, if someone wanted to ask the purist question, "what type of call semantics does Python use, call-by-reference or call-by-value?" the answer will have to be, "Neither... and both." the reason is because calling conventions are less important to Python than object type.

if an object is mutable, it can be modified regardless of what scope you're in... as long as you have a valid object reference, the object can be changed. if the object is *immutable*, then that object cannot be changed no matter where you are or what reference you have.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting list elements in-situ is possible, but not by going forwards through the list. Your code just plain doesn't work -- as the list shrinks, you can miss out examining elements. You need to go backwards, so that the shrinking part is behind you, with rather horrid code. Before I show you that, there are some preliminary considerations:

First, how did that rubbish get into the list? Prevention is better than cure.

Second, how many elements in the list, and what percentage are likely to need deletion? The higher the percentage, the greater the likelihood that it's better to create a new list.

OK, if you still want to do it in-situ, contemplate this:

```
def list_cleanup_fail(alist, is_bad):
    i = 0
    for element in alist:
        print "i=%d alist=%r alist[i]=%d element=%d" % (i, alist, alist[i], element)
        if is_bad(element):
            del alist[i]
        i += 1

def list_cleanup_ok(alist, is_bad):
    for i in xrange(len(alist) - 1, -1, -1):
        print "i=%d alist=%r alist[i]=%d" % (i, alist, alist[i])
        if is_bad(alist[i]):
            del alist[i]

def is_not_mult_of_3(x):
    return x % 3 != 0

for func in (list_cleanup_fail, list_cleanup_ok):
    print
    print func.__name__
    mylist = range(11)
    func(mylist, is_not_mult_of_3)
    print "result", mylist
```

and here is the output:

```
list_cleanup_fail
i=0 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=0 element=0
i=1 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=1 element=1
i=2 alist=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=3 element=3
i=3 alist=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=4 element=4
i=4 alist=[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=6 element=6
i=5 alist=[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=7 element=7
i=6 alist=[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=9 element=9
i=7 alist=[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=10 element=10
result [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]

list_cleanup_ok
i=10 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] alist[i]=10
i=9 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] alist[i]=9
i=8 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] alist[i]=8
i=7 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] alist[i]=7
i=6 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] alist[i]=6
i=5 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] alist[i]=5
i=4 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9] alist[i]=4
i=3 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9] alist[i]=3
i=2 alist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9] alist[i]=2
i=1 alist=[0, 1, 3, 6, 9] alist[i]=1
i=0 alist=[0, 3, 6, 9] alist[i]=0
result [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

```
def listCleanup(listOfElements):
    i = 0
    for element in listOfElements:
        if(element.meetsCriteria()):
            del(listOfElements[i])
        i += 1
    return listOfElements

myList = range(10000)
myList = listCleanup(listOfElements)
```

is the same as

```
def listCleanup(listOfElements):
    i = 0
    for element in listOfElements:
        if(element.meetsCriteria()):
            del(listOfElements[i])
        i += 1

myList = range(10000)
listCleanup(listOfElements)
```

?

Comment: @Daniel: yes if you correct the typo, last line should be `listCleanup(myList)`

Comment: Remember, every "name" in Python is just a reference.  Mutable objects are modified in-place unless you explicitly duplicate them.